# Смещается фоновая картинка при смене разрешение

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Ребят всем привет такая проблема меняю разрешение а фоновая картинка уходит вправо[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот код https://jsfiddle.net/tas2qowy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас блоки которые под картинкой делались как flex элементы. Без указания `flex-wrap:wrap;` и они задают min-width для страницы (Ну или ещё что-то) трудно судить без исходного html и css. Уберите все лишни элементы и убедитесь что фоновое изображение портиться именно из-за нехватки места или ещё чего, или показывайте код...

Comment: Убрал блоки нижние все всеравно, вот код https://jsfiddle.net/tas2qowy/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackStar1991/5d4cp98f/2/  То что я и говорил flex-wrap:wrap; + .container зафиксировал ширину

Comment: что сделать нужно чтобы пофиксить?

Comment: @Данилыч вы эти ужасные цифры уберите в margin width и везде ..применяйте flex или grid

Comment: @Данилыч Я же прикрепил ответ